# Passing values between classes and pages using data binding in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms, parameter-passing

I want to pass the values from ViewModel class to model and then i want to bind the values of model class with page which is detail page of Master detail page.. I want to show User name and Email after login success.Every thing work fine but User name and email does not display in Home Page .
This is my model class

```
 public class User
    {
    private string name;
    private string email;
    public  string Email

            {
                get { return email; }
                set { email = value; }
            }
    public  string UserName

            {
                get { return name; }
                set { name = value; }
            }
    }
```

here is my viewmodel

```
      public class LoginVM
        {
User user;
         public async void Login()
                {
//the _user store Email,UserName and Password after calling GetEmployeePassword()
                     var _user = await azureServices.GetEmployeePassword(Employees.Email,Employees. Password);
                    if (_user != null)
                    {
                        if (_user.Email == Employees.Email && _user.Password == Employees.Password)
                        {
                             await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("success", "Login success", "OK");

        //passing Email and User Name to User Model
    //Here is my Problem
                            user = new User()
                            {
                                Email = _user.Email,
                            UserName=_user.UserName
                            };


                            var masterDetailPage = new MasterDetailPage1();

                            masterDetailPage.Master = new MasterDetailPage1Master();
                             masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
                            Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
                        }
                        else
                            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Login fail", "OK");
                    }

        }
```

this is page1(Home Page) Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyProject.Views.Profile.Page1"
 Title="Home" >

                <StackLayout Margin="5,30,5,5">
        <Entry x:Name="UsernameEntery" Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="UserName"/>
        <Entry x:Name="EmailEntry" Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Email"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Page1 CS

```
public partial class Page1:ContentPage
    {
        User user;
        public Page1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            BindingContext = user= new User();
        }
    }
```

Please help me if anybody understand what i want.i will give more info if anybody need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to pass in the `User` object when you create your page

```
masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Page1(user));
```

then in your page, set the `BindingContext`

```
public partial class Page1:ContentPage
{
    User _user;
    public Page1 (User user)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = _user = user;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot its really helpful. why not you pass this object to User class and then assign these values and after that bind it with page1

Comment: actually i want to do this   public class User {
    private string name;
    private string email;
public user(Employee emp){Email= emp.Email; UserName=emp.UserName}
public string Email{
                get { return email; }
                set { email = value; }
            }
    public  string UserNam { get { return name; }
                set { name = value; } } }   and in page1 class  public partial class Page1:ContentPage{ //again here is problem 
    User _user; public Page1 ()
    { InitializeComponent ();  BindingContext = _user = user;} }  how i set binding context

Comment: the example I gave you shows you how to pass in a User object and set the BindingContext